# When has Wonder Woman died?

Tags: dc, comics, episode-identification, wonder-woman

I know Wonder Woman has died in canon before, but in which issue did this happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Neron kills Wonder Woman in [*Wonder Woman Vol 2* #124](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_2_124). She's not 'Uncle Ben dead' which means she can be resurrected later as the new Goddess of Truth.**

[image: Neron blasts Wonder Woman and her skeleton is seen, she is then seen lying on the ground dead with Neron looking victorious and the other heroes horrified]

**General Steppenwolf kills the Wonder Woman from Earth-2 in [*Earth 2, Vol 1*](https://supermanrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Earth_2_(Volume_1)).**

[image: Wonder Woman and Superman fight the hordes, Wonder Woman calls out to Superman who is being held back; he shouts back "NO! Diana! Steppenwolf! He--" as Steppenwolf is seen charging up behind her; Steppenwolf then spears Diana through her back]

**Artemis briefly takes over as Wonder Woman before being killed by the White Wizard in [The Challenge of Artemis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Challenge_of_Artemis) (*Wonder Woman Vol 2*. #92-100).**

[image: Artemis as Wonder Woman lays dying on the ground before calling out to Diana to take her body back as she is Wonder Woman and he has dishonoured it]

**Circe kills her in [*War of the Gods Vol 1.* #3](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/War_of_the_Gods_Vol_1_3)**

[image: Wonder Woman and Circe fight before Circe catches Diana in her spell grasp; the spell is so strong it completely disintegrates her]

**Circe kills Wonder Woman (again) in [*War of the Gods part 22*; The Demon #17](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/the-demon-17/4000-69777/).**

[image: Circe captures Wonder Woman in her spell who is struggling against it]

Answer (score 1):

In *Joker 10*, (yes, there was a 10th issue of the joker series, even though, it previously only had 9 issues.) one of the Joker's victims (and his last victim to die from the JLA.) is Wonder Woman, she died strangled by the Joker during a battle on the Statue of Liberty. She used the Lasso of Truth on the Joker, but the Joker was able to remove the lasso and attaches it to her neck, and attaches the other side to the statue's sharp edge.

[image: Wonder Woman captures the Joker with the Lasso of Truth who escapes from it and then uses it to hang her from the Statue of Liberty whilst she is in a state of shock/confusion]

Comment: The Joker explains [later in the comic](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Joker_Vol_1_10) that they aren't dead: "They're clinically dead -- No pulse, no breathing! And yet, **as long as the brain waves aren't flat, technically they're still alive!**"

Comment: It's pointed out later in the comic that a) The JLA [aren't actually dead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9rm9.png) (for some unknown reason) and b) That the whole destruction of the JLA is likely a figment of his fevered imagination

Answer (score 1):

One of the most bizarre killers of Wonder Woman was the villain Egg Fu.
In *Wonder Woman* 142 (Oct. 1965) he captured Wonder Woman's love interest Steve Trevor and zapped him with a special ray which apparently turned him into a living bomb.

[image: Egg Fu captures Steve in his magnetic beams; Steve is jovial but Egg Fu informs him that the beams are turning him into an atomic bomb]

Egg Fu sends him flying to destroy a fleet Wonder Woman is protecting. She cannot stop him however and Steve explodes while she tries to protect her, which kills them both.

[image: A massive explosion is seen in the sky above the the navy; one officer remarks of Wonder Woman's sacrifice]

Afterwards the Amazons fly over the area and gather every particle of Wonder Woman and use a machine to recreate her.

[image: The Amazon Swan Fleet glides over the explosion area collecting all the particles in the air; all the particles are in a big pile on a table with a massive laser-like device above them; Hippolyta turns on the device asking Hera to help her]