# Is Wonder Woman invincible?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-2017

In the movie, the lead antagonist said this about himself:

> It takes a god to kill a god.

And we learn that

> Diana aka Wonder Woman is the daughter of Zeus, the so-called god-killer he gifted to the Amazons - the birth of a new god.

Is what he said true? Assuming that to be a yes, then if he had indeed killed all others of his kind, does that mean that upon his defeat, there is none left who can kill Diana?

Comment: Are you assuming that there are no other gods but the Greek pantheon? All that he was claimed to have killed were the Olympians.

Comment: @Paul *shrugs* I can't say I know enough. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: What is a god to a non-believer

Comment: If we're going by the general DC universe, then there's plenty of Gods to around (therefore plenty of people capable of killing WW).  The Egyptian pantheon (the source of Black Adam's power), The Lamb (aka a thinly veiled Jesus analogy), and the inhabitants of both Apocalypse and New Genesis.

Comment: Related (but not dupe): [Does Wonder Woman need to use her bracelets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81742/21267)

Comment: And also related What if bullet hit the Wonder Woman? https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75700/what-if-bullet-hit-the-wonder-woman/75708

Answer (score 10):

#### Hardly. The DCEU Wonder Woman is a character surrounded by myth, legend and hyperbole. Unable to be killed? Not even close to the truth. Ares is an unreliable narrator.

[image]

When modern Wonder Woman in Batman v. Superman faced Doomsday, it was clear she was outmatched. Without the intervention of Superman and Batman's Kryptonite spear, alone she would have simply been beaten to death. Doomsday just kept getting more powerful with each injury she caused.

Diana is amazing. She is formidable, but it is clear she can be beaten by an enemy capable of dealing out more damage, outfighting her, or using an attack she simply cannot overcome, which Doomsday seemed quite capable of doing if he had been given time.

You have to look at the gods the way they see themselves. Before the arrival of aliens on Earth, the Greek gods were the most powerful beings they knew. Assuming there were no other gods, from their perspective, only other gods or monsters from their mythology had the magical or physical capacity to defeat them. From their perspective, at least until other aliens arrived, "only a god could defeat a god."

Answer (score 5):

She hasn't died in the movies yet, so we cannot make claims about what can kill her there. In comic continuity [she has died](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154895/when-has-wonder-woman-died) to a variety of opponents, including one of Darkseid's family (Steppenwolf).

Trying to reenact Baldur's birthday festivities by having people hit her with weapons while she just sits there probably wouldn't go very well for her, though. She does try to avoid or block attacks, presumably there is a reason for that.

Comment: In mythological continuity, Diomedes injured Ares, who then fled, during the Trojan War and Diomedes definitely isn't a god.

Comment: I don't think it is ever implied in the Iliad that Diomedes could have actually killed Ares. A better analogy is that Ares fled from an annoying bee sting. (There's probably also an element of "A god fighting for the *Achaeans*, rather than the Trojans, wouldn't have run screaming from a mere flesh wound" to the episode.)

Comment: Of humorous relevance -- there could be another reason she blocks them - [As shown here](https://i.redditmedia.com/oZi2OdXFpbBQqX_IRThlzcwsqbGRjvZoucECffKRDFQ.jpg?w=547&s=7863c4d0225d1ec96c9f8b40194886b4)

Comment: @chepner I should have included that context, my intent was simply to mock Ares, while also pointing out that they could still be injured unlike Baldur who could only be injured by mistletoe.

Comment: @K-H-W, that should be posted as an answer purely so it can be upvoted infitely